# Specifying local docker container registry in vscode using Google Cloud code

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-code

I am trying to use a local docker container registry as my imageRegistry .
I created a registry by -

```html
docker run –d –p 5000:5000 –-name registry registry:2
```

I have tagged and pushed my image to localhost:5000, and I can see it running by docker images.

I have modified my launch.json as -

```html
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run/Debug on Kubernetes",
            "type": "cloudcode.kubernetes",
            "request": "launch",
            "skaffoldConfig": "${workspaceFolder}/skaffold.yaml",
            "watch": true,
            "cleanUp": true,
            "portForward": true,
            "imageRegistry": "localhost:5000"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I do a Run on Kubernetes,

```html
I get an error  waiting for rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
pod/serviceb-847d79694c-6lxbd: container server is waiting to start: localhost:5000/serviceb:latest@sha256:*** can't be pulled.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using a local cluster solution such as minikube, Docker's built-in Kubernetes cluster, kind, microk8s, or k3s.  Although these clusters are running on your machine, they're running within a virtual machine and so their `localhost` is the VM, not your machine.  So your private registry is not accessible within the cluster.